# Add/remove class working but clicking on new class doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Sorry for the bad title wording!

I have the JS:

```
$(".add").click(function(event)
{
   cid=event.target.id; 
   alert("add class changed");
   $("#"+cid).addClass("del");
   $("#"+cid).removeClass("add"); 
});


$(".del").click(function(event)
{
   cid=event.target.id; 
   alert("del class changed");
   $("#"+cid).addClass("del");
   $("#"+cid).removeClass("add"); 
});
```

And some html like this:

```
<a class="add" id="1" href="#">test a</a>
<a class="add" id="2" href="#">test b</a>
<a class="add" id="3" href="#">test c</a>
```

When I click on one of the "tests" I get the "add class changed" alert and the HTML shows it's class has been changed to "del".

However when I click on one of the changed "tests" the function for something with a del class doesn't run, just the add one again.

So the class is changing and displaying accordingly, but the click function for the corresponding class isn't happening.
Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT:**
Needed a "LIVE" event.
The following code works:

```
$(".add").live({
           click: function(event)
               {
                  cid=event.target.id; 
                  alert("add class changed");
                  $("#"+cid).addClass("del");
                  $("#"+cid).removeClass("add");
               }
               });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(".add")` just selects elements that *at that moment* have the `add` class. It doesn't mean the click event will magically be assigned to other elements when their classes change.

This can be achieved, though, by using the JQuery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to bind the events.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like what I need!
However even this code:   $(".add").live({
    click: function()
       {alert("worked");}
   }); gives me the error "$(".add").live is not a function"

Comment: Is your JQuery version very old? One `live` method was added in 1.3. Other overloads (the one you are using) was added in 1.4, I think. Please refer to the documentation.

Comment: Wow my jquery is 1.2.1! I don't even know how I managed to have that in my project...
The code works great with my changes (in EDIT).
Thank you so much for your help, it is very appreciated.